# ReactJS + Cypress E2E testing

Tags: reactjs, e2e-testing, cypress

a quick question for anyone with React + Cypress experience - writing my first set of E2E tests and here's whats bugging me :

```
cy.visit('http://movinito.docker.localhost:3000/company/subcontractors');
```

works, but

```
cy.visit('/company/subcontractors');
```

doesn't work as expected (redirects me to the dashboard after login and stays there when I try to assert a pathname includes 'subcontractors').

my baseUrl in the cypress.json is

```
{"baseUrl": "http://react_frontend.movinito.docker.localhost:3000"}
```

and it generally works (in case that was what you suspected).

I would like to use the shorter, nicer version `cy.visit('/company/subcontractors');` instead of the long winded retype of the baseUrl...

Might be important to add that prior to the .visit I use a

```
cy.request('POST', 'http://movinito.docker.localhost/user/login?_format=json', {name,pass});
```

to [successfully] log in... As I said the whole thing works but I can't make use of the baseUrl and have to use the .visit command with the full environement based url...

Here is the [working] full test code

```
   describe('Subcontractors section', ()=> {
        it('renders properly', ()=> {
            const { name, pass } = {name: 'info@batcave.com', pass: '123#456'}

            cy.request('POST', 'http://movinito.docker.localhost/user/login?_format=json', {
                name,
                pass
            });

            cy.visit('http://movinito.docker.localhost:3000/company/subcontractors');
//    
// I want to replace the above line with cy.visit('/company/subcontractors')
//
            cy.location('pathname').should('include', '/company/subcontractors');
            cy.get('[data-cy=page-title]').should('have.text', 'Subcontractors');
        })
    });
```

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong:
You mention this one is working:
```'http://movinito.docker.localhost:3000/company/subcontractors'```
but this one is not:
```'http://react_frontend.movinito.docker.localhost:3000'```
You are using two different URL's. What happens if you change the second one to:
```'http://movinito.docker.localhost:3000'```

Comment: let me rephrase what I mean : I expect the baseUrl to concatonate with the string I pass into cy.visit function.

Using just cy.visit('/company/subcontractors') gets my test stuck on the dasbhoard, where as passing in the full url like this -> cy.visit('http://movinito.docker.localhost:3000/company/subcontractors') works as expected.... I log in and am redirected to my subcontractors page. Why is there a difference in behaviour here? I want to use cy.visit('/company/subcontractors') so I can just switch the baseUrl depending on the environment - I don't want to type the full url every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm, I read the documentation about visit() and request(), this should work to:

```js
describe('Subcontractors section', ()=> {
  it('renders properly', ()=> {
    cy.visit({
      url: 'http://movinito.docker.localhost/user/login?_format=json',
      method: 'POST',
      body {
        name,
        pass
      }
    })

    cy.visit('/company/subcontractors')
    cy.location('pathname').should('include', '/company/subcontractors')
  })
});

// cypress.json
{
  "baseUrl": "http://react_frontend.movinito.docker.localhost:3000"
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem was with the server and redirects...

http://react_frontend.movinito.docker.localhost:3000 and
http://movinito.docker.localhost:3000

are synonymous on my machine but cypress doesn't see it that way, so I just removed the "react_frontend" bit and it started working... 

I've accepted your answer though - thank you for your input!

Comment: Check, so we were basically back to the point of my comment yesterday :). At least it is solved.